# The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-active-directory

Running powershell script from C# application in Azure AD.

Added below DLL reference

- System.Management.Automation
- Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PSModule.Resources
- Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PSModule

---

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                runspace.Open();
                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Import-Module AzureAD -Force;");
                pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$password = ConvertTo-SecureString " + "\"abc1234\"" + " -AsPlainText -Force");
                pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (" + "\"abc@abc.com\"" + ", $password)");
                pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Cred");
                pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Get-AzureADApplication -Filter " + "\"DisplayName eq " + "\'PortalTestApp\'" + "\"");
                var result = pipeline.Invoke();
```

Getting Error:

> The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

Comment: `Install-Module AzureAD`
Try that first?

Comment: Are you building for x64? What do you get in the error stream if you _only_ run `Import-Module AzureAD -Force`? (E.g. `Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", pipeline.Error.ReadToEnd().Select(err => err.ToString())));`)

Comment: Also, what you're doing is probably much more complicated than directly calling the Azure AD Graph API. Do you have any reason you _must_ use the PowerShell module?

Comment: Philippe Signoret Yes, I want to 
1. Set ForwardingAddress in Set-Mailbox for OffBoarding user.
2. Change OU Move-ADObject -Identity "OU=ManagedGroups,DC=Fabrikam,DC=Com" -TargetPath "OU=Managed,DC=Fabrikam,DC=Com" 

This is not available with Azure AD Graph API.

Comment: Hi Mike, I added as you suggested, i am getting following error,
Exception calling "ShouldContinue" with "2" argument(s): 
A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: PowerShellGet requires NuGet provider version '2.8.5.201' or newer to interact with NuGet-based repositories.

Comment: [-] The NuGet provider must be available in 'C:\Program Filesx86)\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies' or 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies'. You can also install the NuGet provider by running 'Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force'. Do you want PowerShellGet to install and import the NuGet provider now?

Answer (score 36):

I had an issue with PowerShell v7, unlike PS v5, you have to import the module after installation with `Import-Module AzureAD`. The error is identical to if you haven't imported it after installing it from a module source like PSGallery.

Answer (score 13):

@user1638526 As mike mentioned, you should install the AzureAD module first.

You can follow the below steps:

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -RequiredVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force

Import-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -RequiredVersion 2.8.5.201

Install-Module AzureAD -Force
```

-Force suppresses the user input prompts and allows the script to run in the background.

Reference: [How do I install the Nuget provider for PowerShell on a unconnected machine so I can install a nuget package from the PS command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406685/how-do-i-install-the-nuget-provider-for-powershell-on-a-unconnected-machine-so-i)

About for how to call PowerShell command or PS1 file using C# you can also refer to [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/) or another [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527513/execute-powershell-script-from-c-sharp-with-commandline-arguments?answertab=active#tab-top).

Hope this helps!

Comment: "Install-PackageProvider: No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'NuGet'. The package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags."

Comment: "Get-InstalledModule" results contain AzureADPreview. "Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable" results contains Nuget and PowerShellGet. As OP describes, calling any AzureADPreview command results in the error "...not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"