# 'Get-AzureADUser' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet in github

Tags: powershell, github-actions, azure-powershell, cicd

I'm scratching my head from last couple of days with this strange issue.
I'm using GitHub workflow to run few powershell commands.

So when I tried to run
`Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $User-email`
I'm keep getting

```
The term 'Get-AzureADUser' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,
     | function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the
     | name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
     | again.
```

I used below commands to install the module and check if the module is installed or not.
It shows up all green.
**Install the Module:**

`Install-Module AzureAD -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force`

**Check If Module installed:**

`Find-Module -Name AzureAD`

or

`Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*AzureAD*'}`

It's shows it is installed.

However if I'm trying to use

`Find-Command -Repository PSGallery -Name Get-AzureADUser` this shows

```
Environments : {[AzureChinaCloud, AzureChinaCloud], [AzureUSGovernment, AzureUS
               Government], [AzureCloud, AzureCloud]}
Context      : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.Core.PSAzureContext
```

my workflow looks like this:

```
- name: Run Azure PowerShell script - Add users to AD Group
    uses: azure/powershell@v1
    with:
      azPSVersion: "latest"
      inlineScript: |
           Install-Module AzureAD -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
           $securePassword = "xxxx"
           $psCred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "clientid" , $securePassword
        Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId "tenat_id" -ServicePrincipal
        $info = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $User-email
        Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "aad_object_id"  -RefObjectId $info.ObjectId
        ....
```

Can anyone help me how can I achieve this?

Comment: This looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56543597/the-term-connect-azuread-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet

Answer (score 2):

Check with the commandlets below:
After Installing Azure ad

```
Install-Module AzureAD -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force
```

Make sure to add to import the module to your library of whatever you are using in your pipeline script.

**`Import-module azuread`**
Or
**`Import-module azureadpreview`**
Make sure to Connect to azure ad using

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential
```

[image]

To get the AzureAD modules to be used.

And then try to give Azure ad commands and you may look into @Azeem's reference.

**`Get-AzureADUser`**

[image]